# Use DMXPY with a Transitions state machine

Tags: python-3.x, methods, transition, nonetype, pytransitions

I am trying to use [DmxPy](https://github.com/trevordavies095/DmxPy) with a state machine written in [Transitions](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions) but trying to pass the DmxPy to the finite state machine is throwing a metaclass error.  It seems output of DmxPy is a Nonetype which is not running within the Transitions state machine.

Does anyone know how to get the following simplistic, non-functioning script working or a variation to cause a light to turn on depending upon the state we are in?

```
class DmxPy:
def __init__(self, serialPort):
    self.serial =serialPort(serialPort, baudrate=57600)
    ...other DMX code...

    def set_red(self, channel)
    ...RGBW color red mix...

def set_green(self, channel)
    ...RGBW color green mix...

def render(self)
    self.serial.write(...DMX code...)
```

The above is simplistic but to run it would be

```
dmx = DmxPy('COM5')
dmx.set_red(1)
dmx.render()
```

or

```
dmx = DmxPy('COM5')
dmx.set_red(1)
dmx.render()
```

The Transitions state machine code example, non-functional code is

```
class State:
    pass

classFSMOpen(State, DmxPy):
    dmx = DmxPy('COM5')
    dmx.set_red(1)
    dmx.render()

classFSMClosed(State,DmxPy):
    dmx = DmxPy('COM5')
    dmx.set_green(1)
    dmx.render()

classFSM(object)
    ...creation of the FSM...
```

From the above code, I am receiving a `TypeError: metaclass conflict` and when I check the type of the DmxPy run code, it tells me it's a `<class 'NoneType'>`.

So, how can I use the DmxPy code within the FSM to change a light based on the state of the FSM?  Or, does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have ciphered a way to make the code work, just not why. And I'm smart enough to not care at this point until the next time it breaks.

I simply changed the two classes by removing the call to the DmxPy code like so

```
class State:
    pass

classFSMOpen(State):
    dmx = DmxPy('COM5')
    dmx.set_red(1)
    dmx.render()

classFSMClosed(State):
    dmx = DmxPy('COM5')
    dmx.set_green(1)
    dmx.render()

classFSM(object)
    ...creation of the FSM...
```

If someone has reason this worked, I'm all ears.